# js loop and selecting other input than clicked

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I struggle with some task. When I focus on input, the value of other inputs should be cleared. Unfortunately my logic inside the loop fails. Why?

*****EDITED** ([Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) tip)

```
function emptyInputArea(e) {

    if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {

        currentElem = e.srcElement;

        for(var i = 0, total = inputs.length; i < total; i += 1) {
            if(currentElem.getAttribute('id') === inputs[i].getAttribute('id')) {
                currentIdx = i;
                console.log('current index: ' + currentIdx);
            }
            //while(i !== currentIdx) {
                //console.log('show inputs for clear: ' + i);
                //inputs[i].value = "";
            //}
            if(i !== currentIdx) {
                console.log('show inputs for clear: ' + i);
                inputs[i].value = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/DaGQZ/8/)**

Comment: *"When I focus on input, the value of should be cleared."* What value? The value in the input? If so, that code is **much** more complicated than required.

Comment: Why do you have a `while` *inside* a `for`.  Your `while` will run forever, unless `i === currentIdx`, in which case it won't run at all.

Comment: What do you intend to clear? Clicked element, or all but clicked element? Also, what is inputs?

Comment: How is `emptyInputArea` called? It looks like an event handler; on what element(s)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What value do you want to clear and when do you want to do that?

Comment: Sorry for lack of description, I just have edited my question.

Comment: T.J. Crowder - You have right, in JSFiddle there is full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this code does what you asked.

```
function emptyInputArea(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    //Process all inputs.
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      //Skip the current input.
      if(inputs[i].getAttribute('id') !== e.srcElement.getAttribute('id')) {
        //Empty all others.
        console.log('show inputs for clear: ' + i);
        inputs[i].value = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just have edited my post to work, but Your solution looks better. That what I meant to at beginning!

Answer (score 0):

How about **[using a PlaceHolder](http://jsfiddle.net/DaGQZ/5/)** instead of what you're doing?

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="some city" />
    <input id="postal-code" type="text" placeholder="some code" />
    <input id="street" type="text" placeholder="some street" />
    <input id="other-details" type="text" placeholder="othe details" />
</div>
```

Or, if you wanna do that with Javascript, try to **[use a "data-" attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/DaGQZ/6/)**:

HTML code:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input id="city" type="text" data-defaultvalue="some city" />
    <input id="postal-code" type="text" data-defaultvalue="some code" />
    <input id="street" type="text" data-defaultvalue="some street" />
    <input id="other-details" type="text" data-defaultvalue="othe details" />
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("input").on("focus", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).data("defaultvalue")) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).on("blur", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val($(this).data("defaultvalue"));
    }
}).each(function() {
   $(this).val($(this).data("defaultvalue")); 
});
```

**[Pure Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/DaGQZ/7/)** code:

```
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
    var myInput = myInputs[i];
    myInput.onfocus = function() {
        if (this.value == this.getAttribute("data-defaultvalue")) {
            this.value = "";
        }
    };

    myInput.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            this.value = this.getAttribute("data-defaultvalue");
        }
    };

   myInput.value = myInput.getAttribute("data-defaultvalue");
}
```

Comment: Buzinas that's very interesting approach, but I wanted to accomplish this in pure JS.

Comment: In my first approach, you don't need to use anything, only HTML. Isn't it good for you?

Comment: I just wanted to learn JS. This is only a educational task :-)

Comment: Hello again - the case was different: when You focus on input others immediately loses their values, not only one You focused :-)

Comment: Only the others, or all your inputs?

Comment: All inputs beside one You focused. Sorry if I mislead You with my poor description :-

Comment: This approach is very interesting too and it's remembers previous value - just great! So many examples to learn. Thank You!